# Win 10 - How to stop folder opening when mouse is hovering it for a while?

Tags: windows-explorer, mouse

I move tons of files manually from a folder to others, and when hovering the mouse to choose the correct folder its common that some folder I just moved something to opens by itself when mouse hovers over it for a little while. I know that if I'm fast it wont happen, but its common that I wait too long and the folder opens... It's a nuisance, I would love to turn this off. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: I am not aware of this being any kind of "feature" or anything else that would have a setting to turn it on or off... are you bumping your trackpad? (If you have one)

Comment: No, it's a desktop, I use a Razer mouse.
 If we let mouse hovering for some 1 sec, the folder open. Sometimes I copy something to a folder, then when moving another thing to another folder I pass over the first folder and it open immediately. I think the time counter keeps working for a while.
Win7 had a way to turn this off (Folder Options/View/Navigation Pane). But on Win10 they removed the option, or moved it somewhere else I cant find.